# I get an error when I use boxplot from pandas with subplots

Tags: python, pandas, plot, boxplot

For example if I have this dataframe and plot a density plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,6))
df.plot(kind='density', subplots=True, layout=(3,2), sharex=False, sharey=False,
fontsize=1)
pyplot.show()
```

It yields

[image: Show image]

The thing is that if I try to do the same with boxplot I get and error:

```
df.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(3,2), sharex=False, sharey=False,
fontsize=1)
pyplot.show()
```

I get the following error:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Thanks

Comment: does `box` not have a required input `by` to group?

Comment: I don't want to group.Just show each boxplot from each column independently.The same way as the density plot.I don't know how I could do it using ```by```

Comment: probably `df.plot.box(by=df.index)`.

Comment: It does the same ```df.plot.box()``` that ```df.plot.box(by=df.index)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's a bug for integer columns. This works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,6))
df.columns=list('abcdef')

df.plot.box(subplots=True, layout=(3,2))
```

Output:

[image]

Or change the column type to `str`:

```
(df.rename(columns=lambda x: str(x))
   .plot.box(subplots=True, layout=(3,2))
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure thats the way to use `boxplot`

See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html?highlight=boxplot#pandas.DataFrame.boxplot)

I think it would be like this so

```
df.boxplot(by=0,layout=(3,2))
```

Comment: You are right.I got that code from a book but It used pandas version 0.18.0. Now I should use it the way you said but I can make it work with your code either. It doesn't yield what I want. Any ideas?